# check field weather expired or not while loading a page cakephp

Tags: database, save, cakephp-2.0

The following function checks if the banner is old enough to make it inactive by setting the status field in the Banner table to 0.

/** 
*
* Checks weather the banners are old enough to be turned back to non-premium
* and change the status to 0 , in case of non-premium
* 
* @return void 
*/

```
   protected function check_status(){
     $non_premium_expire = 5*24*60*60;
     $premium_expire = 14*24*60*60;
     $data = $this->Banner->find('all');
     foreach ($data as $Banners) {
            if ($Banners['Banner']['is_premium'] == 0) {
                if ((time() - strtotime($Banners['Banner']['created'])) > $premium_expire) {
                     $this->Banner->id = $Banners['Banner']['id'];
                     $this->Banner->saveField('status',0);
                }
            else if ($Banners['Banner']['is_premium'] == 1) {
                if ((time() - strtotime($Banners['Banner']['created'])) > $non_) {
                    $this->Banner->id = $Banners['Banner']['id'];
                    $this->Banner->saveField('status',0);
                }
            }
     }
   }
}
```

from mybanners() function. i.e. the check_status() function should be called when users open
/site-name/mybanners

I have called the check_status() function from mybanners() function shown below

```
public function mybanners()
    {


        $this->check_status();
        $this->layout = 'index';
        $this->loadModel('Banner'); 
        $loggedUserId   = $this->Auth->user('id');
```

My problem is that the one field status is not getting updated in the database even after trying set() and updateAll() function. Any solutions? I am newbie in cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The working code is below.

```
** 
*
* Checks weather the banners are old enough to be turned back to non-premium
* and change the status to 0 , in case of non-premium
* 
* @return void 
*/

   protected function check_status(){
     $non_premium_expire = 5*24*60*60;
     $premium_expire = 14*24*60*60;
     $data = $this->Banner->find('all');
     //pr ($Banners);
     //pr ((time() - strtotime($Banners['Banner']['modified'])) > 5*24*60*60);
     //pr ((time() - strtotime($Banners['Banner']['modified'])) > 14*24*60*60);
     //die();
     foreach ($data as $Banners) {
            if ($Banners['Banner']['is_premium'] == 0) {
                if ((time() - strtotime($Banners['Banner']['modified'])) > $non_premium_expire) {
                     $id = $Banners['Banner']['id'];
                     //pr ("in non premium loop");
                     //pr ($id);
                     //die();
                     $data_one = array('id' => $id , 'status'=> 0, 'modified' => false);
                     $this->Banner->save($data_one);
                     //$this->Banner->clear();
                }
            }
            if ($Banners['Banner']['is_premium'] == 1) {
                if ((time() - strtotime($Banners['Banner']['modified'])) > $premium_expire) {
                     $id = $Banners['Banner']['id'];
                     //pr ("in premium loop");
                     //pr ($id);
                     //die();
                     $data_one = array('id' =>$id , 'status'=> 0, 'modified' => false);
                    //pr ($data_one);
                    //die();
                     $this->Banner->save($data_one);
                     //$this->Banner->clear();
                }
            }
     }
   }
```